# SharePoint Claims authentication and web.config role authorizations

Tags: claims-based-auth, web-config, roles, role-provider, authorization

I am trying to secure a few application pages with role base authorizations can't seem to get it working , if I set a deny rule for all users the rule works, but anything with a specific group or username doesn't work I am using claims based authentication.

and direction is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try different approach. You can secure application in page code rather to alter/add web.config file(s).

This link is bit old but for general info will be ok:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878359(v=office.12).aspx#SecuringAppPages_ValidatingUserPermissions

I still have few scars left from my last fight with Sharepoint web.config.